# how can I update multiple values in a firestore map using only one write without overwriting the entire map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this code will overwrite the entire map in firestore

```
Map<String, String> map = {};
for (MapEntry e in someGientMap.entries) {
  map[e.key] = e.value;
}
await db.doc('document path').update({
  'FirestoreGiantMap': map,
});
```

and this code will write the document too many times

```
for (MapEntry e in someGientMap.entries) {
  await db.doc('document path').update({
    'FirestoreGiantMap.${e.key}: e.value,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Combing the two techniques leads to:

```
Map<String, String> map = {};
for (MapEntry e in someGientMap.entries) {
  var key = 'FirestoreGiantMap.' + e.key;
  map[key] = e.value;
}
await db.doc('document path').update(map);
```